# (iPhone app) error: too many arguments to function 'URLWithString:'

Tags: iphone, string, url, format, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a URL string however it's saying there are too many arguments. My code is below:

```
-(IBAction)tweetRandom {

 //NSLog(@"CALLED");
 test = 100;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/%i", test]]; // problem line

}
```

Anyone know how to format the URL? Was hoping there was something by the name of `URLWithFormat` but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `stringWithFormat:` like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/%i", test]]];
```